# gstreamer: stream g726 encoded audio over rtp

Tags: gstreamer

I am trying to stream adpcm (G726),32kbps audio from a host to a client through
RTP:

I have tried following commands from the client(receiver) and the host(sender).
Both boards are connected through IP.

I am getting "internal data flow error" at the receiver once i run the cmds on
the sender:

RECEIVER:

```
gst-launch -v udpsrc port=3004 caps="application/x-rtp” ! rtpg726depay !
ffdec_g726 ! alsasink
```

SENDER:

```
gst-launch -v autoaudiosrc ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! ffenc_g726
bitrate=32000 ! rtpg726pay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.104 port=3004
```

If I try the same with pcm, alaw encoder and decoder, then streaming works
fine. I can hear the live audio(when I speak on sender's Microphone) into
receiver's speakerphone:

commands I am running in this case:

RECEIVER:

```
gst-launch udpsrc port=3004 caps="application/x-rtp" ! rtppcmadepay ! alawdec 
! alsasink
```

SENDER:

```
gst-launch autoaudiosrc ! audioconvert ! audioresample  ! alawenc ! rtppcmapay
! udpsink host=192.168.1.104 port=3004
```

This seems to be an issue in the pipeline?

here is the full error I am getting at the receiver

```
///////////////
root@am335x-evm:~/EVM4# gst-launch udpsrc port=3004 caps="application/x-rtp" !
rtpg726depay ! ffdec_g726 ! alsasink
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0: Internal data
flow error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(2625): gst_base_src_loop ():
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0:
streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)
Execution ended after 20828810227 ns.
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Comment: I don't see much programming content here. try asking on [su]

Comment: You need to better specify your caps with rate, channels and, encoding-type at least.